# How to dismiss modal uitabbarcontroller from its own child view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

My `viewControllerOne` modally present a `uitabbarcontroller` which have 5 tabs. On fifth tab I have `resetViewController` which is obviously the child of uitabbarcontroller.

How to dismiss the `modally presented uitabbarcontroller` from its own child viewcontroller **(**`resetViewController`**)**.

Comment: have you tried `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`?

Comment: @Virussmca some odd behaviour, i think my viewControllerOne dismiss but uitabbarcontroller is still on the screen and 20px gap at the bottom.

Comment: which method you used to present `tabbarcontroller`?

Answer (score 1):

Since it was the tab bar controller that was presented, it will have a reference to the presenting view controller, so if you have the tab bar controller do the dismissal, it should forward that message to viewControllerOne. Try this:

```
[self.tabBarController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```